# How to return error from firebase function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have this function:

```
export const createUser = (email, password) => 
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    return error
});
```

I import this function into my React component, and if it throws an error set the message as it's state:

```
const process = createUser(email, password)
console.log(process)
```

But the above logs the functions full details. I tried to catch on the frontend, to get the `process.error` while put the error into bracket in the exported function, and also tried to get the message somehow like this: `process.A.i.L.message`, but nothing's worked. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is async, you should return a `Promise` instead of returning the result from `.catch()`. I haven't tested the solution yet but you should be able to do something like this:

```
// definition
function createUser(email,password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(res => resolve(res))
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                reject(error)
            })
        })
}

// when you are calling the function
createUser(email, password)
    .then(process => console.log(process))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```